# Excel 2011 Mac: Paste selection into new tab, name tab cell A1 return to sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm new to vba. I tried to record a macro of me doing the steps above. No such luck. I want to:

Paste selection into new tab, name tab the text in "cell A1", then return to sheet 1

I think it might have to be done in two steps, but I'm really not sure how to proceed. Any advice?

Gratefully,
Masin

Comment: Could you post the code outputted by the recorded macro and explain in detail why it does not do what you desire? Please read over the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub addtab()
'
' addtab Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast
    Sheets.Add
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Sheet3"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Brouwer, Mark "
    Range("I23").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlFirst
    Sheets("November").Select
End Sub
```

Above is the code. It creates a new tab, and then crashes with the message below:

Run-time error "9"

Subscript out of range

Thank you for the help!